# Short story about the discovery of iron that may be from Nathaniel Hawthorne

Tags: story-identification

I have scant memories of it, but it was similar to "Puck of Pook's Hill". A man from an ancient age relates his adventure when he went on a journey to get the knowledge of iron and in exchange had to give up one of his eyes.

Comment: Possibly related to the Nordic legend of Odin, who traded an eye for wisdom?

Comment: For sure, but I do not remember that the story contained distinctively Nordic names. The setting was vaguely Celtic, although it was so vague that it could have been Nordic or even Amerindian or Polynesian, although the iron was a technology alien to those cultures.

Comment: I don't know the story you referenced ("Puck of Pook's Hill"). In what way is this story similar to it?

Comment: For reference, "[Puck of Pook's Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puck_of_Pook%27s_Hill)"